# Algorithm to efficiently sum N boolean numbers.

Tags: algorithms, boolean-algebras

I am looking for a fast algorithm to do the following task: Given $N$ numbers $a_i, i=1,..., N$, where $a_i$ can be equal to $0$ or $1$, compute the number $s \equiv \sum_{i=1}^N a_i$ in base 2. Example: $N=3$, $a_1=0,a_2=a_3=1$, $s=10$.

There is a naif algorithm to do this task: take $a_1$, then compute $a_1+a_2$ in base $2$ by adding bit-by-bit $a_2$ to $a_1$ and by taking care of the carry, then sum $a_3$ to $a_1+a_2$ in the same way, etc... until the sum $s$ is computed.

Do you know an algorithm that can do this task in a fewer number of operations than the naif algorithm? Any improvement over the naif algorithm would be fine for me.

Thank you
Best,
Michele

Comment: Take a quick peek at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight

Comment: And just increasing $s$ if $a_i\neq 0$?

Comment: Dear Yosef, thank you for your suggestion. I have looked at the Wikipedia page, but it is not clear how this can help building an algorithm ore efficient than the naive one.

Comment: You need to look for "binary counter".  However much of the technical literature is devoted to doing as much in parallel as possible.

Comment: This belongs on stackoverflow or cstheory.stackexchange.com (probably the former).

Answer (score 1):

This seems like more of a programming question than a math question.  The usual approach is to precompute a 256-element table giving the Hamming weight of the different 8-bit bytes.  Then scan through your input string 1 byte at a time, looking up the weight of each byte in the table, and summing those weights.

Notice that some processors have so-called "population count" instructions that do what you're asking directly in the hardware.  These come with recurring stories/urban legands that the instructions were added at the request of the US National Security Agency, which uses them to find closely matching strings for codebreaking purposes.

Comment: The OP is talking about adding bits, while you are talking about adding bytes.

Comment: He is talking about processing the bits in byte sized chunks, which can offer a constant speedup for large inputs when presented as a byte stream.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger, thanks for the clarification.  The question is now why use bytes, and not, say nybbles or other word sizes.

Comment: The answer is that it depends how much memory you are willing to trade for how much speed gain.  Even in embedded systems, using a kilobyte as a scratch pad to speed up computations by a factor of 8 is reasonable; using 64 Kbytes may not be.

Comment: Hello, my question is a question about the best existing algorithm, it is not about how to program it: Suppose that any logical operation between two boolean variables A and B (A & B, A ^ B, ...) is the basic operation taking one unit of time. What is the algorithm doing the task with the smallest time?